Set Theory; A pair doesn't contain the empty set, so why the power set of a pair contains the empty set
All this is based on the Naive Set Theory book, I understand that each set indiscriminately has a subset that doesn't contain any of his elements, the empty set, but with the Axiom of Pairing this shouldn't be True because to create a pair, the two sets must be equal to one of the two

{x ∈ A: x = a or x = b} 
{a, b}

So, this pair by logic, doesn't contain the empty set, because the empty set is not equal to a or b, because to be equal, a or b must contain the same elements of the empty set, since the empty set is empty this is not true.
Now in the Axiom of Powers this change, and I want to know why

P({a,b}) = {∅, {a}, {b}, {a, b}}

Why is the empty set a possible subset of a pair if the pair only contains two sets?

Axiom of powers. For each set there exists a collection of sets thai con
tains among its elements all the subsets of the given set.
In other words, if E is a set, then there exists a set (collection) P such that
if X ⊂ E, then X ∈ P.
The set P described above may be larger than wanted; it may contain
elements other than the subsets of E. This is easy to remedy; just apply
the axiom of specification to form the set {X ∈ P: X ⊂ E}. (Recall that
"X ⊂ E" says the same thing as "for all x (if x ∈ X then x ∈ E).") Since,
for every X, a necessary and sufficient condition that X belong to this set
is that X be a subset of E, it follows that if we change notation and call
this set P again, then
P = {X: X ⊂ E}

I feel the key to understand why, is in the line

{X ∈ P: X ⊂ E}. (Recall that
"X ⊂ E" says the same thing as "for all x (if x ∈ X then x ∈ E).")

But still, it doesn't make any sense for me, a pair only contains two sets and nothing more so, the subset of a pair cannot be the empty set?

$\forall x(x\in\emptyset\Rightarrow x\in y)$ is true as $x\in\emptyset$ is always false.

The empty set is a subset of every set, by the above comment. The empty set may not be an element of ${a,b}$ (unless $a$ or $b$ happens to be the empty set), but it is always a subset of ${a,b}$. The verb "contain" is ambiguous as it can refer to elements or subsets, and should generally be avoided.

The two elements of ${a,b}$ are $a,b$. The four subsets of ${a,b}$ are $\emptyset, {a}, {b}, {a,b}$; naturally these are also the four elements of the powerset $\mathcal P({a,b})$ since the powerset is the set of subsets.

The set of integers doesn't contain the empty set either.

In general, the empty set is always a subset of all sets. Because $x \in \emptyset$ is a false statement, and thus $∅ \subset \{,\}$. For $∅⊂\{a,b\}$ holds true, you must verify: $∈∅⇒∈\{,\}$.
From something false, something true always follows in an implication.

"this pair by logic, doesn't contain the empty set, because the empty set is not equal to a or b"; "Why is the empty set a possible subset of a pair if the pair only contains two sets?"
The natural language is ambiguous. Here, "contains" means 2 things:
A pair $P=\{a, b\}$

contains $a$ and $b$ as elements:
$$a\in P,$$
contains the empty set and three other sets as subsets:
$$\varnothing\subseteq P.$$


So, belonging '∈' or 'contain' is not the same as 'inclusion' '⊂' or 'subset', a pair has two sets that belongs to it and nothing more, but any set by nature includes the empty set as subset, if that's true then the empty set doesn't belong to a pair?

Exactly!${}{}{}$
